# É possível incluir OCR no java android ? Existe alguma biblioteca OCR no JAVA ?

Tags: java, android, ocr

Já pesquisei alguma coisa sobre OCR na internet e encontrei a solução da GOOGLE, mas é muito cara.

Comment: Depende para o que tu necessita. Eu utilizei a `Vision` em uma aplicaçao que eu leio as placas de carros e funcionou perfeitamente. https://developers.google.com/vision/

Comment: Da uma olhada no projeto deles e ve se serve pra ti https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples